# Access configured CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath outside of Startup.Auth.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, owin

I'm using cookie authentication with OWIN in a .NET MVC 4.5 setup.  I set up the cookie authentication configuration in Startup.Auth.cs (code below) and I would like to access the LoginPath that I set in CookieAuthenticationOptions in a controller so that if, for whatever reason, my LoginPath changes, I only need to change it in one place.  So just looking for something like

```
context.GetCookieAuthenticationOptions().LoginPath
```

Is there a way to access the CookieAuthenticationOptions outside of Startup.Auth.cs, or is my only option here to do something like add an appSetting in Web.config and then use that instead?

Startup.Auth.cs code, I would like to access LoginPath outside of this file.

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("Login"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = _expirationTimeSpan,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
            },

        });
```

Comment: I am also interested in how you do this in .NET Core if it has changed. I added the bounty trying to find this out.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain why not just have the path as an option that is passed /injected to the startup which is also accessible externally via that same class/service. Or am I oversimplifying my understanding of what it is you want to access.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that or have the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` encapsulated in a something like a factory that would give you access to the instance that was passed to the middleware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. If you look closely, the cookie options object is stored in the `AppBuilder` class private `_middleware` collection. There is no way to access this property (except reflection).

You can however store the cookieOptions object in the Owin context:

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    // ...
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    // ...
};

app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new MyCookieAuthOptions(cookieOptions));
```

In the controller you can then access it like this:

```
var cookieOptions = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<MyCookieAuthOptions>().Options;
```

Owin context only supports `IDisposable` object, therefore we need to wrap `CookieAuthenticationOptions` in a `IDisposable` object:

```
public class MyCookieAuthOptions : IDisposable
{
    public MyCookieAuthOptions(CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieOptions)
    {
        Options = cookieOptions;
    }

    public CookieAuthenticationOptions Options { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```